# Find GitHub repository through the API without knowing the owner

Tags: github, repository, github-api

**I am trying to crawl through a list of repositories from a requirements.txt file to get information (e.g. licenses) about the associated repositories I want to be using.**

Thus, I do not have the `full_name` of the repository neither the `owner` information.
e.g. I need to find:

```
 https://github.com/schutera/HeartSeg-Dataset
```

Without knowing `schutera`

Currently I am trying by requesting https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=name:HeartSeg-Dataset
but this gives me empty items:

```
{
  "total_count": 0,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [

  ]
}
```

I also [found](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories) the option to do a search `in:name`, but I can not wrap my head around how to use this properly:

HeartSeg `in:name` matches repositories with "HeartSeg" in the repository name. But yeah well, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is me again. So I have not been too far off with what I already did and presented in my question:**

the `in:name` is properly used as such
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=HeartSeg-Dataset+in:name

works like a charm, and the remainder is dictionary crunching. Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: The full code base for my github license crawler can be found here: https://github.com/schutera/GithubLicenseCrawler - for how much it is worth. *flies away*